# DatePicker onchange event not firing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a button and a textbox. Onclick of the button datepicker pop up appears and user selects a date from the calender pop up and the selected date is populated in the text field.

Now I want to fire an event when the result is populated on the textfield. Onchange event does not work for this as textfield onchange event is fired only if it loses focus. In my case it is changed from an external source.

Hence I thought to fire an onSelect event for the button click. But again event is not triggered.

here is my code

```
<input type="text" class="textbox_small" name=""
            value="" id="txt_node" disabled="disabled"
            onchange="fnChangeTime();" />
<input type="button" name="" value=""
            class="timePicker_button" id="lnk_hpd"
            ; style="background-image: url('images/Date_time_picker.gif'); width: 29px; height: 20px;"
            onclick="" onselect="" "disabled"/></td>

$('#'+fnParseIDForJ('lnk_hpd')).click(function () {
             NewCssCal('txt_node','ddmmyyyy','arrow',false, null, null, null, fnInterimSave, 'txt_node');

    });
$('#lnk_hpd').datepicker({
    onSelect:function(datesel){
    alert("hello");
   //   alert("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
     // $(this).change();
    }
});
```

Here no event is triggered. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You're using an input type="button" whereas the JQuery datepicker works best with regular text input fields. Frankly I'm not sure if the "button" input type even exists, and if it does, it's more akin to a submit button than an actual input field.

Comment: But I need to use a button.

Comment: Try putting your jQuery code inside the document ready event.
$( document ).ready(function() { 
// HERE
});

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or snippet on which we can rely to see what exactly is not working? Without the library you are using it is hard to see what is the problem. Here is a jsfiddle where I do get the click event but obviously I had to remove the `datepicker` thing http://jsfiddle.net/ou8pryu3/2/.

Comment: I found your `datepicker` thing (jqueryui, right?) and your code seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/ou8pryu3/3/. Are you sure you did not forgot to remove the `disabled="disabled"` attribute of the input? Obviously if it is disabled you won't get anything.

Comment: Yes I have taken out the disabled property. Well your fiddle is trigger an event on textbox change not the button select event

Comment: @QuentinRoy. we can write into and read from a `disabled` element using JavaScript.

Comment: @JSantosh Yes but all events won't be triggered. `datepicker` does not work (by itself) if the input is disabled. http://jsfiddle.net/ou8pryu3/8/.

Comment: @QuentinRoy. once check my  answer , there is a disabled attribute on input field. And I said we can we handle things on disabled element using JAVASCRIPT . May be some events might not work I accept it , but here `change` event is working using JS

Comment: You're handling the DOM events from the button, not the disabled input, then you create a custom one.

Answer (score 7):

1.Open datepicker on `text box` on clicking button , so you have to use id of text box , not button and a method `$('#txt_node').datepicker('show');` to show the datepicker.
2.If `change` event triggered , the datepicker will be kept open, it is not closed so the line `$('#txt_node').datepicker('hide');`

Check this.

```js
$('#txt_node').datepicker({
  onSelect: function(datesel) {
    $('#txt_node').trigger('change')
  }
});
$('#lnk_hpd').click(function() {
  $('#txt_node').datepicker('show');
})

$('#txt_node').change(

  function(event) {
    $('#SelectedDate').text("Selected date: " + this.value);
    $('#txt_node').datepicker('hide'); // if youdon't hide datepicker will be kept open

  })
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="textbox_small" name="" value="" id="txt_node" disabled="disabled" onchange="fnChangeTime();" />
<input type="button" name="" class="timePicker_button" id="lnk_hpd" ; onclick="" onselect="" "disabled" value='Open' />
<br/>
<br/>
<span id='SelectedDate'></span>
```

Comment: `change` event looks a bit useless though and the fact that using it prevents the date picker to automatically close upsets me a bit. I would prefer to do the logic inside the `onSelect` handler (or to call a function) which looks simpler and more appropriate.

Comment: @QuentinRoy. Of course it is. But OP want to use it , so i added it. we can acheive the same with `onSelect` without `change` event.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. It works fine here. But its not triggering on my code. I am using this datetimepicker http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/datetimepicker-tutorial.htm

I am not able to add an external source on fiddle. Hence I have posted the link.

Comment: there are many other date time picker plugins like [this](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) which are active an now  and being updated regularly. The plugin you are using , I didn't find an option something like `onselect`. so i suggest , change the plugin

Comment: if this helped you , then can you accept it answer @user123

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar using:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="NewDate" style="display:none" />
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#NewDate').datepicker( 
        {
        showOn: 'button', 
        buttonImageOnly: true, 
        buttonText:"", 
        buttonImage: 'img/calendar.png', 
        onClose: function(date) { 
            if(date !="") {
                alert(date);
                } 
            }
       })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple uncomment **$(this).change();** this and It'll automatically work. This will tell the datepicker function to trigger **Change()** after selecting or Choosing a Date.

Answer (score 0):

for this I use **onSelectedDateChanged={handleChange}**
*handleChange* is my function for handle form data changes
// handle date case from (Datepicker flowbite component)

```
const handleChange = (target) => {
    // handle date case from deadline input (Datepicker component) 
    if (target instanceof Date) {
        setValues({
            ...values,
            deadline: format(target, 'MMMM dd, yyyy')
        });
        testRegExp({ name: 'deadline', value: target });
        return null;
    }
    // handle text input case
    const { name, value } = target;
    setValues({
        ...values,
        [name]: value
    });
    testRegExp(target);
}
```

__
in others inputs I use :

```
onChange={e => handleChange(e.target)}
```

---

hope this help you .